# como obter o índice (de origem 0) da maior repetição dentro de uma string em php

Tags: php

Ex: `Run::posicaoMaiorRepeticao(‘ccddddeee')` deve retornar 2, pois dddd é a maior repetição e seu índice inicial é 2.

Eu cheguei até aqui, mas o principal da function ainda não consegui fazer:

```
class Run
{
    public static function posicaoMaiorRepeticao($str)
    {
        throw new Exception(‘Implementar’);
    }
}
```

```
echo Run:: posicaoMaiorRepeticao('abbcccddddeeeeeefffffffffggg');
// 16


echo Run:: posicaoMaiorRepeticao('ddddeeeeeefffffffffgggggggggggggggggghhhhh’);
// 19
```

Comment: O que aconteceria se fosse `abcaaaaaaaaaaaa`? Retornaria `0` ou iria retornar `3`?

Comment: Fiz o que você pediu em C#, estou traduzindo para o php.

Answer (score 0):

> Isso não funciona com caracteres multibyte!

Na condição da postagem poderia simplesmente fazer:

```
$string = 'ddddeeeeeefffffffffgggggggggggggggggghhhhh';

$QntPorCaractere = count_chars($string, 1);

arsort($QntPorCaractere);
reset($QntPorCaractere);

echo strpos($string, key($QntPorCaractere));
```

**[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5decab4c578404c7b4f85525b0789a80c0c18ab7)**

Isso irá retornar a posição da primeira da letra que mais está repetindo na string. *Isso é, se for `gabcdefggg` seria `0`, porque o `g` é quem mais se repete e a primeira posição de `g` é em `0`.*

---

O `count_chars` usando o parâmetro `1` irá retornar exatamente a quantidade de ocorrências (no valor) e qual foi o caractere (na chave) da array, ou seja:

```
array(5) {
  [100]=>
  int(4)
  [101]=>
  int(6)
  [102]=>
  int(9)
  [103]=>
  int(18)
  [104]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Neste caso o `103` é o `g`, na tabela ASCII, para que possamos ordenar, afinal queremos aquele que tem mais ocorrências, usamos o `arsort()`.

Então pegamos o `103`, que está contido na chave da array usando `key($QntPorCaractere)` e usamos ele dentro do `strpos()` que pega a primeira ocorrencia.

---

*Pode parecer errado usar `strpos($string, 103);` ao invés de usar algo como `strpos($string, pack('C', 103));`. Mas o manual do PHP diz que "If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.", então como está no formato int o `103` passa para `g` internamente pelo `strpos`.*

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se existe alguma função do php para fazer isso de forma mais prática, mas eu fiz um algoritmo bem simples que faz isso:

```
<?php
function posicaoMaiorRepeticao($x)
{
    $index = -1;
    for ($i=0;$i<strlen($x);$i++)
    {
        if ($ultimo != $x[$i])
        {
            $ultimocount = $count;
            $count = 0;
            $ultimo = $x[$i];
        }
        else
        {
            $count++;
            if ($count > $ultimocount)
                $index = strpos($x, $x[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $index;
}

$n = "abbcccddddeeeeeefffffffffggg";
echo posicaoMaiorRepeticao($n); //Output: 16
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/nSK9Sf).